# Android add different icons to a list

Tags: android, listview, icons, rss

I am getting RSS feeds from two different URLs (Say twitter and Facebook). I want to add these two to the same list and add their respective icons. I have tried many things.

The below code is for parsing

```
Element _titleE = (Element) entry.getElementsByTagName("description").item(0);

                        String _title = _titleE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();
                          _linkE.getFirstChild().getNodeValue();

                        RssItem rssItem = new RssItem(_title);
                        rssItems.add(rssItem);
```

Here is how I'm adding it to the array adapter to display. The image which is there in R.id.Label gets set (it is present in XML).

```
aa = new ArrayAdapter<RssItem>(this, R.layout.list_item,R.id.label, rssItems);
            rssListView.setAdapter(aa);
```

Comment: Show your code. And what is exactly your problem?

Comment: @Olegas I have edited the question with the code,. please help

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue some days before and got help from this tutorial:
http://www.anddev.org/android_filebrowser__v20-t101.html
They are basically implementing a custom adapter which creates the list items and sets their icons.